# Questioning in the same JSP page

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts

I have a problem creating one application. For example I have a List or Array of string lines - these are questions. I have a servlet and JSP page, in JSP page there is a button "next" a one question has to be printed in JSP at a time when next button is pressed.

Please give me some advise how can I make this work.

I have a struts action class in which i have my code to place the question:

```
public class SecondWriteAction extends Action {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final String SUCCESS = "success";

    /**
     *
     */
    protected int count = 0;

    /**
     * 
     */
    protected Collection<QuestionsBean> questionsBeansCollection = new ArrayList<QuestionsBean>();

    /**
     * This is the action called from the Struts framework.
     * @param mapping The ActionMapping used to select this instance.
     * @param form The optional ActionForm bean for this request.
     * @param request The HTTP Request we are processing.
     * @param response The HTTP Response we are processing.
     * @throws java.lang.Exception
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        if (session.getAttribute("questioningTimeCount") == null){
            session.setAttribute("questioningTimeCount", request.getParameter("timeCount"));
        }

        int timeCount = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("questioningTimeCount").toString());

        WriteFormBean formBean = (WriteFormBean) form;
        QuestionsBean questionsBean = new QuestionsBean();

        questionsBean.setSentence(formBean.getQuestion());
        questionsBeansCollection.add(questionsBean);

        if (session.getAttribute("countFromJsp") != null) {
            int countFromJsp = Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("countFromJsp").toString());

            if (countFromJsp == 1){
                session.setAttribute("questionsBeansCollection", questionsBeansCollection);
            }

            if (countFromJsp <= 0) {
                questionsBeansCollection.clear();
                questionsBeansCollection = new ArrayList<QuestionsBean>();
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        QuestionsHandler handler = QuestionsHandler.getInstance(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/data/sentences_" + timeCount));

        count = count + 1;
        request.setAttribute("question", handler.getQuestions().get(count));
        request.setAttribute("count", count);

        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/student/secondWrite.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

        return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

In JSP page I count them and when questioning is finished I am trying to forward to ohter JSP page.

```
<%
    if (request.getAttribute("count") != null){

        int count = 11 - Integer.parseInt(request.getAttribute("count").toString());
        out.print("<p>Liko klausimų: " + count + "</p>");
        session.setAttribute("countFromJsp", count);
        if (count == 0){                                            
            if (Integer.parseInt(session.getAttribute("questioningTimeCount").toString()) > 1){                                                
                %>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                        $.post('update', function(data) {});
                </script>                                                
                <%                                                                                                
            } else {   
                //response.sendRedirect("content/informantForm.jsp");                                                                                          
                //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/content/informantForm.jsp");
                //rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        }
    }
%>
```

Problem is I can't. If I use `RequestDispatcher` in JSP page I get an exception

> cannot forward after responce has been commited

If I try to access servlet with jQuery it's all OK but the `RequestDispacher` doesn't work and I can't redirect to other JSP event from servlet.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you try something ? Show what you did and it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> *If I use RequestDispatcher in JSP page I get an exception*
>
> ```
> cannot forward after responce has been commited
> ```

JSP as being a view technology is implicitly part of the HTTP response. Every template line in JSP get written to the response. In order to be able to change the response, the response should be completely untouched and blank. But this is not necessarily the case inside a JSP.

Move that Java code to an action or servlet class which will run far before the JSP. Java code [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) belong in JSP files anyway.